Would there be issues with using non-standard opt-out messages and keeping track of consent myself?
We're currently sending a message containing 'Reply STOP to unsubscribe' at the beginning of every SMS conversation with users (as per the Messaging Policy). Often, they unsubscribe using the STOP keyword, but a few months later sign up again (signing an SMS communication consent checkbox). The issue is, because they've unsubscribed using the default keyword, they don't have the opportunity to opt back in since they're not aware they're supposed to receive messages again.
Would it be a violation of Twilio's guidelines to keep track of opt-outs ourselves, given that we honor them 100% of the time? That is, could we direct users to unsubscribe using a keyword other than one of the default keywords (making sure to not send them messages until they opt back in), to be able to easily reinstitute them into the messaging if needed?
